# Animate input placeholder to become a label?

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'd love to get something like this going with TailwindCSS and inputs, is this possible? This specific component is written in Vue.js, I believe.

```html
<div class="v-input theme--light v-text-field v-text-field--is-booted v-text-field--enclosed v-text-field--outlined">
   <div class="v-input__control">
      <div class="v-input__slot">
         <fieldset aria-hidden="true">
            <legend style="width: 0px;"><span>​</span></legend>
         </fieldset>
         <div class="v-text-field__slot"><label for="input-145" class="v-label theme--light" style="left: 0px; right: auto; position: absolute;">Link to visit (optional)</label><input id="input-145" type="text"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="v-text-field__details">
         <div class="v-messages theme--light">
            <div class="v-messages__wrapper"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-counter theme--light">0 / 200</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

[This is how it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nudGe.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I have found 3 resources regarding this. Do check them out.

[Material Tailwind](https://material-tailwind.com/) [Tailwind Components](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/material-ui-textfield-1) [Dev](https://dev.to/chrsgrrtt/floating-label-input-with-react-and-tailwind-2e5h)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).